# Find dynamically created CheckBoxes (C++ Windows Form Application)

Tags: winforms, checkbox, c++-cli

by runtime I create CheckBoxes:

```
unsigned int number = getNumber();
CheckBox^ box;

for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
{
    box = gcnew CheckBox();
    box->Name = i.ToString();
    box->Text = i.ToString();
    box->AutoSize = true;
    box->Location = Point(10, i * 30);
    this->panel->Controls->Add(box);      
}
```

Now I want to get all CheckBoxes, that are NOT checked:

```
std::map<unsigned int, std::string> values;

for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
{
    String^ name = i.ToString();
    CheckBox^ box = dynamic_cast<CheckBox^>(this->panel->Controls->Find(name, true));
    if (!box->Checked)
    {
        String^ text = box->Text;
        values.insert(std::pair<unsigned int, std::string>(i, msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(text)));
    }
}
```

My problem is, that by runtime I get a NullReferenceException (in the line I check if the box is unchecked).
But all the CheckBoxes exist.

PS: I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Update 3

Comment: Why are you using ^? you expected something like Bitwise XOR assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1), the signature of Find is:

```
array<Control^>^ Find(
    String^ key,
    bool searchAllChildren
)
```

It returns an array.  But you're `dynamic_casting` it to a CheckBox^.  This fails, so returns a NULL pointer.

You can make your code work with

```
    CheckBox^ box = dynamic_cast<CheckBox^>(this->panel->Controls->Find(name, true)[0]);
```

This will dynamically cast the first element of the control array to a checkbox, which is what you want.

Normally, you should find a way to iterate through everything in the array, but in this case, since you're certain find will return one and only one result, using the [0] notation is ok.

Note, you shouldn't even need `Find`.  (It's not very efficient.)  You should just be able to iterate over `this->panel->Controls`.  I'm not good at managed C++, but it should be something along the lines of:

```
foreach (control in this->panel->Controls)
{
    if (control is CheckBox and static_cast<CheckBox^>(control).Checked) {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```